# AFNetworking post request not getting through to Sinatra app

Tags: objective-c, ruby, sinatra, afnetworking

I'm trying to post a request from my iPhone with a Sinatra API I made.  Currently all my Sinatra app is doing is printing out the request that has been sent to it.  This is the code for that:

```
post '/profile' do

    puts "#{params}"
end
```

My objective-c is pretty simple as well.  All it does is send a post request to my API:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURLString];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:JSON, @"json", nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/profile" parameters:dictionary];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
[operation start];
```

When JSON (in line 3 of the obj-c) is a very short string, such as @"test", Sinatra prints it out correctly like this:

```
{"json"=>"test"}
```

When I use the actual JSON profile data, which is a very long JSON blob, Sinatra prints it out as this:

```
{"json"=>"(null)"}
```

I can't figure out why the long blob is getting through.  I am 100% sure that i'm passing the correct string, but Sinatra is not receiving it.  My current theory is that Sinatra has a max character limit on requests, but I am new to Sinatra and Ruby, and I have no idea how I'd test that.  What is going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

First off, thanks Kjuly for your suggestions.  I figured out that I was wrong on the character limit on Sinatra thing.  In obj-c I'm doing a log of the dictionary that has the JSON blob on line 3, and it has the json blob.  However, when I log the body of the NSMutableURLRequest on line 4, the body is empty.  When I use my tiny JSON blob, the body is filled.

Does NSMutableURLRequest have a character limit?  Can anyone think of a reason why it would not accept my very large dictionary with the large JSON blob, but not with the small one.

Thanks!

**UPDATE AGAIN:**

The request body now fills correctly.  I had to add this line into line 3:

```
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
```

Now I am getting this response back in the HTTPResponse from Sinatra:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/html"
```

Sinatra is now just printing

```
{}
```

Instead of {"json"=>"(null)"}

Still not sure what's going on.

**Update 3**

Okay, what I thought was the HTTPResponse from Sinatra - the text/json stuff - was because I was returning a text/html from Sinatra back in AFNetworking.  I have now checked the body that Sinatra is receiving, and my giant JSON blob is in there.  However, "params" is still empty.

Anyone have any idea why?

**FIXED IT**

Looks like when you post JSON to sinatra you have to read the body of the request directly.  In Sinatra, you do this like so:

profile = JSON.parse(request.body.read.to_s)

Then profile is your parsed object.

Comment: Yeah, tried that.  Same result.

Comment: Maybe you did something wrong, try the sample code official give.

Comment: Note, `JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:` is a class method, you need to use it like `[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest...]`.

Comment: Instead of doing `JSON.parse` in Sinatra, just make sure to set the `Content-Type` HTTP header of the `NSURLRequest` to `application/json`. JSON parsing will work automatically.

Comment: @mattt added "[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];"  When you say "should work automatically," do you mean that I can remove JSON.parse and request.body.read will return an object, or that "params" will be populated?

Comment: Yes, unless I'm mistaken. It should just be in params if you set the Content-Type correctly.

Comment: params still showing an empty object, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `AFJSONRequestOperation` instead, here's a sample code:

```
// Fetch Data from server
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gowalla.com/users/mattt.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation * operation =
[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                success:^(NSURLRequest * request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, id JSON) {
                                                  NSLog(@"Name: %@ %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"first_name"], [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"last_name"]);
                                                }
                                                failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

Or you can visit the [WIKI PAGE](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking), see **Step 4: Download and Parse JSON**.

Comment: I changed it to using the class method instead of the instance method with AFJSONRequestOperation.  Still not working.  I also tried it with a short JSON blob, and it went through.  I still think there's a character limit getting enforced somewhere in here.  I'm just not sure where.